# Converting AJAX'd-in XML to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

I have a web page that allows the user to select a category from a dropdown list. The category relates to a table that is derived from an XML file that is AJAX'd in. I intend to use some JS code to read the contents of the XML file and create a table based on the values therein. (In other words, the XML files could create tables with completely different columns, which is why I don't want to hard code anything, but would rather have it built programatically.) I also don't want to use XSLT or any other methods that would create a second set of files; the XML files used are to be considered the "sources of truth".

I can get an XML file to load, but I'm having difficulty navigating the structure in order to read column names from the first child element.

```
<xml>
 <item>
  <number>Number</number>
  <image>Image</image>
 </item>
 <item>
  <number>123</number>
  <image>123.jpg</image>
 </item>
</xml>
```

I'd like to be able to read the first set of `<item>` elements and use their text values to generate the `<th>` elements in the table. And then fill in the table with the rest of the XML content.

I've tried items[0].childNodes[0], but it picks up the line breaks (which I don't want to remove from the XML source files).
I've also tried items[0].children[0], but I get "Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference".

Here is my code thus far:

```
const vPathToJSON = "../JSON/";
const vPathToXML = "../XML/";

var vCategoriesJSON = "categoriesJSON.txt";

//  Perform functions after DOM is readyState
$("document").ready(
    function() {
        getFromFile(vPathToJSON, vCategoriesJSON, "JSON")
            .then(fillCategoriesDropdown)
            .then(getFromFile(vPathToXML, "acMitigation.xml", "XML"));
    }
);

//  Use jQuery AJAX "GET" function to import from file and parse as 
requested
function getFromFile(pFilePath, pFileName, pParseType) {
    var vCompletePath = pFilePath + pFileName;

    switch(pParseType) {
        case "JSON":
            return $.get(vCompletePath)
                .then(function(returnedText) {
                    return JSON.parse(returnedText);
            });
        case "XML":
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: vCompletePath,
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    console.log("Success!");
                    fillMainTable(xml);
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("Unsuccessful!");
                }
            });
            break;
    }
}

//  Fill Category dropdown dynamically based on returned JSON file values
function fillCategoriesDropdown(pReturnedJSON) {
    for (i = 0; i < pReturnedJSON.length; i++) {
        var vNewOption = document.createElement("OPTION");
        vNewOption.text = pReturnedJSON[i].category;
            document.getElementById("id_CategorySelect").appendChild(vNewOption);
        aListOfCategories[i] = pReturnedJSON[i];
    }
}

function fillMainTable(pXML) {
    var items = pXML.getElementsByTagName("item");
    // ???
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: oops, you can ignore the "aListOfCategories" line, that should have been deleted

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best strategy, but it's working at least.

FYI, I changed the name of the function to more accurately describe what it does.

The main problem I was facing was that it was picking up the empty text nodes, which made navigating the element tree confusing.

```
function getColumnNames(pXML) {
    var entriesElement = pXML.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].nodeName; //finds <item>
    var items = pXML.getElementsByTagName(entriesElement); //array of <item> elements

    var columns = []; //column elements and names
    var j = 0;

    //  childNodes starts at 1 and goes up by 2 to skip empty text nodes in <item>
    for (i = 1; i < items[0].childNodes.length; i += 2) {
        var elementName = items[0].childNodes[i].nodeName;
        var elementValue = items[0].childNodes[i].textContent;

        columns[j] = {
                "elementName":elementName,
                "elementValue":elementValue};
        console.log(columns[j]);
        j++;
    }
}
```